# NameError during python xml parsing

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

```
>>> stringx
'<?xml version="1.0"?><data><country name="Liechtenstein"><rank>1</rank><year>2008</year><gdppc>141100</gdppc><neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/><neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/></country><country name="Singapore"><rank>4</rank><year>2011</year><gdppc>59900</gdppc><neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/></country><country name="Panama"><rank>68</rank><year>2011</year><gdppc>13600</gdppc><neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/><neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/></country></data>'
>>>
>>>
>>> e = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(stringx)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'xml' is not defined
```

Can someone suggest what am I missing here? is it the xml code or the way I am trying to parse?

Comment: Post the full code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import xml.etree.ElementTree`

Looks like you have forgotten this.

Reference the documentation for proper usage.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Edit: Thanks @mzjn. Your are correct. I was just passing by and notice OP forgot the import. Didn't actually try it out. Credit goes to you :)

Comment: Just adding `import xml` won't work. You have to do `import xml.etree.ElementTree` in order to use `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring()` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

python 3

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
stringx='<?xml version="1.0"?><data><country name="Liechtenstein"><rank>1</rank><year>2008</year><gdppc>141100</gdppc><neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/><neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/></country><country name="Singapore"><rank>4</rank><year>2011</year><gdppc>59900</gdppc><neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/></country><country name="Panama"><rank>68</rank><year>2011</year><gdppc>13600</gdppc><neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/><neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/></country></data>'
e = ElementTree.fromstring(stringx)
print(e) # <Element 'data' at 0x7f7e7a4cc1d8>
```

Answer (score -1):

seems like you are missing import!

> from xml.etree import ElementTree

```
stringx='<?xml version="1.0"?><data><country name="Liechtenstein"><rank>1</rank><year>2008</year><gdppc>141100</gdppc><neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/><neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/></country><country name="Singapore"><rank>4</rank><year>2011</year><gdppc>59900</gdppc><neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/></country><country name="Panama"><rank>68</rank><year>2011</year><gdppc>13600</gdppc><neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/><neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/></country></data>'

e = ElementTree.fromstring(stringx) #will wok fine!
```